# Does Web8.5 Database Script require Database Admin Account to run?

Tags: web8.5, database, installation

Our DBAs are not allowed to have full DB Admin accounts in production (Company policy). Does the Web 8.5 scripts absolutely need full DB Admin to run?

Is there a list somewhere of the specific  privileges a user account must have to successfully run the SDL scripts without having full Admin rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is No.

Before you create a Content Manager database, run the SQL script CreateTridionSYSUser.sql (for example from SQL*Plus) located in the directory Database\Scripts\Oracle\Tools on your SDL Web installation media

The privileges and roles created for this user are the minimum requirements for database installation.

Answer (score 4):

Does it requires DB Admin account? I think no, but it requires user which must be able to execute all SQL scripts. These scripts require rights like create/update/delete over both your newly created databases and system databases.

For example, `CD_BROKER_CRETE_LOGIN.sql` script in installation folder has following command:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.sql_logins where name='cd_broker_user')
BEGIN
  CREATE LOGIN "cd_broker_user" WITH PASSWORD = 'cd_broker_password'
END
GO
```

As you can see, it requires access to system databases (sys.sql_logins), so you must have these rights. In any case, I suggest you check all sql scripts in your installation folder and check if your uses has rights to execute them all.

P.S.

SQL scripts are in `\SDL Web 8.5\Database\Scripts\mssql` folder of your installation.

**UPDATE:**

Official docs found [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-5CE16752-3BF3-43AF-A0B4-998BCA928DD1&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-EA943C95-AC45-40AA-A87E-3F1E39DB5373.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5CE16752-3BF3-43AF-A0B4-998BCA928DD1) states that you need to be logged in as a user with sufficient security clearance.
Also, [following page](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-1E8C5BC2-B755-4038-86B2-8DDA5AE2E6EA&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-BF0C63CF-A201-4C56-9305-534F2792C1A7.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-1E8C5BC2-B755-4038-86B2-8DDA5AE2E6EA) explains that system db admin must perform setup of SQL server. Besides this, [following page](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-60D90F72-E98A-4314-BB60-7C1DE0A043E5&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-BF0C63CF-A201-4C56-9305-534F2792C1A7.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-60D90F72-E98A-4314-BB60-7C1DE0A043E5) states that following is required:

> PowerShell scripts prompt you for the following information:
>
> - DBA and user credentials (unless you created an Oracle SDL Web administrator user)

To answer your question in comment, no I don't think that that sort of list exists. I am afraid you will have to analyze all sql scripts and compile list of rights required by yourself. :(

Also, documentation states on multiple instances that DBA is required, so I guess you will have to request it.

Comment: The user needs rights for granting roles, e.g `GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_SCHEDULER` even if you have a SYSDBA account in the oracle world, you still need to have the Admin option. I think it does require some level of Admin, hence my question, if  there is a list of  privilledges that is required then maybe we can create an account with all those rights, not every organisation is wiling to give Admin rights in Production.

Comment: Your answer got  me digging and I found this  : The privileges and roles created for this user are the minimum requirements for database installation. Before you create a Content Manager database, run the SQL script **CreateTridionSYSUser.sql** (for example from SQL*Plus) located in the directory Database\Scripts\Oracle\Tools on your SDL Web installation media.Many thanks

Comment: yes, that's why I said you should analyze all of the sql scripts. :(